# Correct antiderivative of $(7x+9)^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have $f(x) = (7x+9)^\frac{1}{2}$

Now, as per the power rule, the antiderivative (indefinite integral) for the above function will be $f(x) = \frac{2}{3}\cdot(7x+9)^{\frac{3}{2}}$
However, if I differentiate $f(x) = f^{\prime}(x)$ then I get $f(x) = 7\times(7x+9)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

I am getting confused about how there are two $f(x)$ for the same $F(x)$.

As per my understanding $f(x)$ -> antiderivative -> $F(x)$ -> differentiate/$F^{\prime}(x)$ -> $f(x)$

How is differentiating $F(x)$ returns two separate functions? Can someone please clarify?

NOTE: I have tried u-substitution where $u$ was $7x+9$.

Comment: This is hard to read.  Do you mean $\int \sqrt {7x+9}\,dx$?

Comment: If $u=7x+9$ then it is true that $\int u^{1/2} du=(2/3)u^{3/2}.$ But you want the integral w.r.t. $x.$

Comment: You can let $u = \sqrt{7x + 9}$, square both sides then differentiate.

Comment: @SagarSharma Can you please add `$$` or `$` to both sides of your MathJax please?

Comment: antiderivative of $(7x+9)^{1/2}$ is $\frac23(7x+9)^{3/2}\frac17$

Comment: apologies for making the question such a mess. Corrected it. Thanks @toby harnish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are assuming that since the antiderivative of $x^{1/2}$ is $\frac23x^{3/2}$ (which is indeed correct) also the antiderivative of $g(x)^{1/2}$ will be $\frac23g(x)^{3/2}$.

This is indeed wrong as
$$\left(\frac23g(x)^{3/2}\right)'=g(x)^{1/2}\cdot g'(x)$$
so the inner derivative is the one causing the issue.

In general there is no "chain rule" for integration (otherwise integration would be easy) besides the one for affine functions, which states that
$$\int f(ax+b)=\frac1{a}F(ax+b)$$

Comment: Thanks. Got it; g'(x) was creating the problem as I was considering g(x) as x and applying the power rule. However, when I differentiated F(x) using the chain rule, I got a different function f(x) because it considered g'(x).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $\int\sqrt{7x+9}dx$:

Substitute $u=7x+9$, $du=\frac{dx}{7}$

$$\int\sqrt{7x+9}dx=\frac{1}{7}\int\sqrt{u}du=\frac{2}{3(7)}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+C=\frac{2}{21}(7x+9)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$

Then, $f'(x)=\frac{2}{21}(\frac{3}{2})(7x+9)^\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{d}{dx}(7x+9)=\frac{1}{7}(7x+9)^\frac{1}{2}(7)=(7x+9)^{1/2}$

I'm guessing you forgot to multiply by $\frac{d}{dx}(7x+9)$ while using the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks. I did u-substitution and found my antiderivative as the one you have shared but cant I just use the power rule for finding the antiderivative instead of going for u-substitution

Comment: @SagarSharma Does this edit help?